# How do I mute and unmute my sound playing in the the button

Tags: android

i am planning to make a sound button and for the button I have two images one for ENABLE and one for DISABLE state for sound.
i want to enable and disable the sound of different buttons through these buttons.

Comment: add checkbox for that. and save the state in SharedPreference.

Comment: Set the volume to 0 when disable, and to whatever you want when enable

Comment: can u share the code

Comment: code depends on your code. There are a lot of ways to play sound, and nobody knows which one you use.

Answer (score 0):

Create just one Button and add something like a buttonstatus. Then you can check the status in your listener.
For example:

```
boolean isPlaying = false;
playPause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
playPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
     if (isPlaying) {
       pause();
     }else{
       play();
     }
       isPlaying = !isPlaying;
     }
     });
```

Comment: if need any more help then please put your comment here

Comment: here u need to create one state button in drawable folder with state

Comment: and based on isPlaying bool you need to handel on click

Comment: if you need that code then plz ping here i put hare